# Сортировка строки по алфавиту с учетом условия

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Как отсортировать содержимое строки по алфавиту, при этом числа должны остаться на своих местах.

Есть строка: `Great43 WA1Y`

Нужно получить, что-то на подобии: `aegrt43 aw1y`

Пробовал разбить на несколько массивов с учетом пробела. 
Потом перебрать, но все равно сортировка происходит по всему массиву.
На выходе получаю `43aegrt 1awy`, как быть с цифрами?

Буду премного благодарен, если подскажете. Можно объяснением или блоком кода.

Comment: запомнить положение цифр и цифры, удалить их отсортировать с пробелами, вставить цифры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В два стрима можно: сначала получаем подстроку с буквами и сортируем, затем небуквенные символы возвращаем на прежние места.

```java
// приводим строку к нижнему регистру
String str = "kjg0Grea t43qwe".toLowerCase();

// получаем отсортированный лист с буквами
List<Character> list = IntStream.range(0, str.length())
        .mapToObj(str::charAt)
        .filter(Character::isAlphabetic)
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// раздвигаем лист с буквами, добавляем
// небуквенные символы на прежние места
IntStream.range(0, str.length())
        .filter(i -> !Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(i)))
        .forEach(i -> list.add(i, str.charAt(i)));

// вывод в строку
list.forEach(System.out::print); // aee0ggjk q43rtw
```

Comment: Стопэ! Дык автор же сам дал тест и он не проходит на данном алгоритме! Тут сортируются все буквы сквозным методом, а просили каждую группу отдельно! Или я не прав?

Answer (score 0):

```
static String parseAndSortLetters(String str) {
    String result = "";
    int current = 0;
    int end = str.length();
    while (current < end) {
        int start = current;
        while (current < end && Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(current))) {
            current++;
        }
        String substring = str.substring(start, current).toLowerCase();
        String sortedSubstring = Stream.of(substring.split("")).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining());
        result += sortedSubstring;

        while (current < end && !Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(current))) {
            result += str.charAt(current);
            current++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Добавьте проверку на `null`!!!